# Button Click WebBrowser vb.net by GetElementByType or Value

Tags: php, vb.net

I'm currently trying to make a login process in my application so everything is working good in part of username - password - security code, but I'm currently having issue about clicking the button of Log in. The website script is common and it's not my side so i'm not able to force people to change their codes.

So this is what i tried in order to achieve a good result but didn't work.

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("click")
```

So yeah the submit itself isn't an ID here is the Log in script :

```
<form onsubmit="Login.send(this); return false">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Log in">
</form>
```

Thanks for reading and i hope someone will help me out in this.

Comment: "submit" is not an id, you could get elements by tag of tag "input" then filter it by some parameter eg if "nnertext = log in then click, you could have easily checked that with dim test = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit") and a breakpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
    If element.GetAttribute("value") = "Log in" Then
        element.InvokeMember("click")
    End If
Next
```

This should work for you!

Comment: And exit for after click.